# SSIS load from Excel Dynamic Named Range

Tags: excel, ssis, named-ranges

I am trying to create an SSIS package that will load data from a named range in an Excel spreadsheet. Because the number of rows we import will be different between loads (and we don't necessarily trust business users to re-define the named range before sending the workbook), the named range needs to be dynamic. This is possible using the `OFFSET` formula: we define the named range as `=OFFSET([reference to header row], 0, 0, [formula that calculates number of rows])`. So far, so good.

However, it appears that SSIS cannot use this named range. It does not appear in the dropdown list of Excel sheets/objects in the Excel Source Editor, and it complains that the object does not exist when I try and input it directly.

Does anyone know of a way of using such a named range in an SSIS load? Or perhaps another way of approaching the problem?

[Note: I'm using Office 2010 and SSIS 2014.]

Comment: I've never done this personally, but I know you can do pretty much anything with a script transformation.   Use one as your source and have it output only the desired rows from your Excel sheet to the dataflow.

Comment: If the columns are static and only the number of rows are going to vary then you could use a SELECT statement in a variable to select a Range of cells which would allow room for future rows to be added. In the SSIS you can then ignore any null lines. e.g. 'SELECT * FROM [mysheetname$B5:J5000]'. This would select the whole range in sheet "mysheetname" from B5 to B5000